# How to determine 'using' declaration for c# library class

Tags: c#

When programming in C# and using a class that's a part of a library for the first time, where do you look to find the name that has to go in the 'using' declaration?

In Java, the package name is *always* listed in the Javadocs for a class. C# doesn't appear to share that norm or tradition.

For example... suppose I'm writing a C# class to use with Unity. It might have the following two 'using' declarations near the top:

```
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleARCore;
```

However, I might eventually need to add a call to GvrCardboardHelpers.Recenter(). When I add that, Visual Studio complains: "The name 'GvrCardboardHelpers' does not exist in the current namespace.

OK, no problem... I think I just need to add a 'using' declaration for it. In Java, I'd Google the class, find an official Javadoc for it, look near the top... and find the package name to include within a matter of seconds.

So... I try that approach with GvrCardboardHelpers... and find https://developers.google.com/vr/reference/unity/class/GvrCardboardHelpers

Oops. As far as I can tell, there's NOTHING on that page that gives any insight into what needs to go into the 'using' declaration. And this seems to be the norm for pretty much EVERY C# library I've encountered.

Clearly, I'm misunderstanding something fundamental & trying to hammer square pegs into round holes. But what? What do "real" C# programmers do when they run into a class that needs a 'using' declaration, but they have no idea what its name is supposed to be?

Comment: Proper documentation always mention the namespace for a class, doesn't have anything to do with C#.  MSDN docs do so at the very top of the article.  If the docs are poor then you can see it back with Object Browser or let the IDE take a guess at it from the squiggles context menu.  Watch out for a "should work like Java" mindset, you'll look in the wrong places.

Comment: FWIW: that's actually the first time I've seen documentation that *doesn't* include the type's namespace (which is the thing you need for the `using` directive). Certainly all the MSDN docs include namespace info.

Comment: That is indeed really bad documentation style. In that linked documentation, you can find namespaces in the "Namespace" node at the very bottom of the tree on the left. But I'm not even sure if that are the namespaces you required, because it doesn't list many or no classes: https://developers.google.com/vr/reference/unity/namespace/Gvr

Comment: The problem is not with poor documentation, but with poor code. This helper does not have namespace. https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/blob/master/Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/GvrCardboardHelpers.cs

Answer (score 3):

I don't. I let the IDE worry about it. Let's say you know that there's a type called `GvrCardboardHelpers`. Type (or paste) that, and it'll probably get a red squiggly. Now: right click on the squiggly, or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (with the caret in or next to `GvrCardboardHelpers`), or click on the quick-fix icon (yellow light-bulb, left gutter), and the IDE will usually offer to add the right `using` directives for you.

Here's what it looks like when you expand the quick-fix menu:

[image]

Comment: On a general note, this only works if the assembly containing `GvrCardboardHelpers` is referenced in the project; if it was (accidentally) not referenced, this helpful tool won't find it.

Comment: ^^^ This is the problem I keep running into. VS can't find it, and I don't know where it's actually supposed to be. I thought GvrCardboardHelpers is supposedly SOMEWHERE inside GoogleVRForUnity_1.170.0.unitypackage... but with Google, who knows. Their documentation is pretty awful to begin with, compounded by their habit of making radical, sweeping changes with every new release that completely breaks every previously-written example, tutorial, Javadoc, and bit of forum-advice & puts everyone back at square one & running on wild goose chases.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, as microsoft documentation says:

> The using directive allow the use of types in a namespace so that you
>   do not have to qualify the use of a type in that **namespace**

To know the namespare where a class resides i suggest you to use the Api Browser provided by microsoft: [Browser API .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api)

for example the **File.Exists** static method is declared in the **System.IO** Namespace:
[File.Exists example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2427.png)

of course if you need to use third party library you have to check the documentation provided by the author.